# Why does a loop with a char as it's index loop infinitely?

Tags: java, loops, char

This loop will continue indefinitely:

```
char a = 100;
for(a=100; a>=0;--a)
    System.out.println(a);
```

Does it happen because a gets promoted to an int value for arithmetic operations and gets widened to 32 bits from 16 bit char value and hence will always stay positive?

Comment: @oldrinb - that only answers the "will it".  The more interesting question is "why".

Comment: @StephenC my comment answered the question in the title. "why" I answered below.

Comment: @Phoenix I've updated my response and in fact you're actually right for the reason why... :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will indeed loop indefinitely -- and the reason you stated is close. It happens because `a` can't represent any number that *doesn't* satisfy `a >= 0` -- `char` is unsigned. Arithmetic underflow is well-defined in Java and unindicated. See the below relevant parts of the specification.

- [§4.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2)

  > The integer operators do not indicate overflow or underflow in any way.

  This means there is no indication of overflow/underflow other than just comparing the values... e.g. if `a` <= `--a`, then that means an underflow occured.
- [§15.15.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.2)

  > Before the subtraction, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is performed on the value 1 and the value of the variable. If necessary, the difference is narrowed by a narrowing primitive conversion (§5.1.3) and/or subjected to boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to the type of the variable before it is stored. The value of the prefix decrement expression is the value of the variable *after* the new value is stored.

  So, we can see that there are two major steps here: binary numeric promotion, followed by a narrowing pritimive conversion.
- [§5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

  > Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
  >
  > - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
  > - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
  > - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
  > - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

  We can see that the decrement expression works with `a` treated as `int`, thus performing a widening conversion. This allows it to represent the value *-1*.
- [§5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

  > A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and range.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the *n* lowest order bits, where *n* is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

  Keeping only the *n* lowest order bits means that only the lowest 16 bits of the `int` expression `a - 1` are kept. Since *-1* is *0b11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111* here, only the lower *0b11111111 11111111* is saved. Since `char` is unsigned, *all* of these bits contribute to the result, giving *65535*.

Noticing something here? Essentially, this all means that Java integer arithmetic is *modular*; in this case, the modulus is *2^16*, or *65536*, because `char` is a 16-bit datatype. *-1 (mod 65536) ≡ 65535*, so the decrement will wrap back around.

Comment: Is this really Arithmetic Underflow?? cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow

Comment: You've still got this wrong.  Integer underflow does happen in Java.  It is just not **indicated** ... as the JLS text that you quoted states.  That is to say, no exception is thrown, and there is nothing you can test directly to see if underflow has happened.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. `char` values are unsigned - when they go below 0, they come back around to 65535.

Swap `char` with `byte` - then it'll work.

Comment: Stephen, you are correct. I was assuming it was like C's char.

Comment: @NickODell well then you should know that the signedness of *plain* `char` is implementation-defined... it's only guaranteed to be able to fit the entire ASCII charset (0 - 127), and C99 ensures it can store at least 8 bits.

Comment: oldrinb, In C, I always clarify whether a variable is signed or unsigned, just to make sure it will work the same on all compilers. Is this necessary even for int's and the like, or just paranoia?

Comment: @NickODell no -- `int` corresponds to `signed int`, `long` to `signed long int`, and `short` to `signed short int`. The distinction happens for `char` because technically *plain* `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are all separate data types.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the `char` type in Java is unsigned, so `a >= 0` will always be true. When `a` hits 0 and then is decremented once more, it becomes 65535. If you just want to be perverse, you can write your loop to terminate after 101 iterations this way:

```
char a = 100;
for(a=100; a<=100;--a)
    System.out.println(a);
```

Code reviewers can then have a field day tearing you apart for writing such a horrible thing. :)